# Reskinning ActiveAdmin using Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to re-skin ActiveAdmin using a Bootstrap template theme. However I need to change the layout of the page to suit.

Is it possible to override the layout of ActiveAdmin to suit what I want? It looks different to normal rails conventions - I'd rather just accomplish it using a regular template and then yield the parts of the content that I need in the order that I need them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ive done something similar before. Check out this Gist https://gist.github.com/bigfive/6017435

Essentially you patch the active admin base controller to use your new layout by overriding their `:determine_active_admin_layout` method

```
# config/initializers/active_admin_patch.rb
module ActiveAdmin
  class BaseController
    def determine_active_admin_layout
      'active_admin_reskin'
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your `active_admin_reskin` layout you can call methods on the Arbre `view_factory` like so

```
view_factory[#{params[:action]}_page"].new(Arbre::Context.new(assigns, self)).send(:build_header)
```

In the gist(https://gist.github.com/bigfive/6017435) Ive made a little view helper for making it easy to call those methods.

Have a look through the active admin source code to see which methods are available to you on various Arbre documents, especially here: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb

Once the markup is changed the way you like, you can `@include 'bootstrap'` into your `active_admin.css.scss` file that the generator created and go nuts.

Comment: Im not sure how your patch works, can you give some clearer idea how to use it ? So far, @import "bootstrap"; in the active_admin.css.scss got bootstrap look and feel. Could you give some instructional guideline ? Thanks.

Comment: The patch changes the way ActiveAdmin works by over-riding that method to return the 'active_admin_reskin' string. Save it to the path mentioned in the comment on the first line.

Then you create such a layout (just a regular Rails layout) in app/views/layouts/active_admin_reskin.html.erb

See the gist that @BigFive linked to.

Comment: I had problems implementing it with the less bootstrap gem. Worked fine when moved to SASS gem and added: @ import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@ import "bootstrap"; in active_admin.css.scss

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer would be putting

@import "bootstrap";

into active_admin.css.scss

Officially, its not supported for now https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/1027

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of AA you are using.

(0.6.0 < commit:ec9996406df5c07f4720eabc0120f710ae46c997):

Include your scss, but encapsulate your css selectors in the `body.active_admin` group. Furthermore, specificity is important, so if you want to override the default styling of AA, you may need to ensure you are overriding the full selector to get the behavior you want.

If you want to find these styles to override them, take a look at [AA's stylesheets](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/tree/master/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin) to see how they style the site be default. Simply include your custom styling after the the AA stylesheet is included.

After commit:ec9996406df5c07f4720eabc0120f710ae46c997

The namespacing of stylesheets has been removed recently, and I have not throroughly tested the implication yet.

Comment: this seems like a nice way of styling it, but I really want to modify the markup that is being produced. CSS alone is not enough to do what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

BigFive's accepted answer worked for me at the beginning but then produced some bugs when rendering custom partials or when rendering errors in forms.

Inspired by his approach I switched to overriding the individual methods that AA uses to dynamically generate the layout (as AA doesn't use a static layout file that can be easily modified).

You can find the available methods in the source code, but it's pretty self-explanatory and begins in the [html element](https://github.com/activeadmin/active_admin/blob/8b4c1b5ef65ebdf77413bcaa955c0f7badb26ffb/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb).

Example:

To add some classes and reorganize the elements:

You can put your style in:

assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss

And your html description in:

config/initializers/active_admin_patch.rb:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    class Header

      alias_method :original_build_site_title, :build_site_title
      alias_method :original_build_global_navigation, :build_global_navigation
      alias_method :original_build_utility_navigation, :build_utility_navigation

      def build_site_title
        div class: "side_bar_top" do
          original_build_site_title
        end
      end

      def build_global_navigation
        div class: "side_bar_content" do
          original_build_global_navigation
        end
      end

      def build_utility_navigation
        div class: "side_bar_footer" do
          original_build_utility_navigation
        end
      end
    end

    module Pages
      class Base

        alias_method :original_build, :build

        # This should be the same as add_classes_to_body but for the html main element
        def add_classes_to_html_tag
          document.add_class(params[:action])
          document.add_class(params[:controller].gsub('/', '_'))
          document.add_class("active_admin")
          document.add_class("logged_in")
          document.add_class(active_admin_namespace.name.to_s + "_namespace")
        end

        def build(*args)
          original_build
          add_classes_to_html_tag
        end

        def build_page
          within @body do
            div id: "wrapper" do
              div id: "details_view" do
                build_title_bar
                build_page_content  
                #build_footer
              end
              div id: "master_view" do
                build_header
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```